# Python 3 - functions beginners exercise

Tags: python, function

Python 3, functions.

**There is the following exercise:**

Write a function that asks the user to enter his birth year, first name and surname. Keep each of these things in a variable. The function will calculate what is the age of the user, the initials of his name and print them.
for example:

```
John
Doh
1989
Your initials are JD and you are 32.
```

Age calculation depends on what year you are doing the track,
you should use input, format etc.

**the given answer is:**

```
def user_input():
  birth_year = int(input("enter your birth year:\n")) 
  first_name = input ("enter your first name:\n")
  surname = input ("enter your surname:\n")
  print ("your initials are {1}{2} and you are {0} years old". format(first_name[0], surname[0],2021-birth_year))
```

when I run this the terminal stays empty,
hope you could help,
thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to run the function using `user_input()`?

Comment: thank you!!! successful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to call your function, so that it gets executed:

```py
def user_input():
    birth_year = int(input("enter your birth year:\n")) 
    first_name = input("enter your first name:\n")
    surname = input("enter your surname:\n")
    print("your initials are {1}{2} and you are {0} years old".format(first_name[0], surname[0], 2021-birth_year))

# Call it here
user_input()
```

Comment: No problem! If my answer helped, be sure to upvote it and click the checkmark next to it :)

Answer (score 1):

The terminal stays empty is because you did not call the function to execute it.

```
def user_input():
    birth_year = int(input("Please enter your birth year: ")) 
    surname = input("Please enter your surname: ")
    first_name = input("Please enter your first name: ")
    print("\n\nYour initials are {1}{0} and you are {2} years old".format(first_name[0], surname[0], 2021-birth_year))

# remember to call the function
user_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Small change:**

You can use the DateTime module to change the year rather than the hardcoded year value.

```
from datetime  import date

    def user_input():
        birth_year = int(input("Please enter your birth year: ")) 
        surname = input("Please enter your surname: ")
        first_name = input("Please enter your first name: ")
        print("\n\nYour initials are {1}{0} and you are {2} years old".format(first_name[0], surname[0], date.today().year-birth_year))
    
    # remember to call the function
    user_input()
```